# Synchronize scrollbars between two elements - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, synchronization, onscroll

How can you synchronize scrollbars between two elements ***without*** recursively calling each event?

Usually you would expect the following code:

```
$div1.scroll(function() {
    $div2.scrollTop($div1.scrollTop());
});
$div2.scroll(function(){
    $div1.scrollTop($div2.scrollTop());
});
```

But in this case, if you scroll $div1 1px, it will scroll $div2 1px as well, which will prompt the $div2 scroll event to fire and re-apply the scroll position to $div1. **While this might not seem like an issue, when this code is applied to a page and you naturally scroll with a mouse, it scrolls in 1px increments because the handlers call eachother and don't allow the scroll to flow.**

So, how would you solve this issue?

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/axtn/a91fsar3/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out a good solution. Debouncing does the trick.

You can use a combination of timers and bools to make sure the element is being scrolled by the user. Thus, when the scroll event is rapidly and consecutively fired (like when a user scrolls down), it prevents the handlers from recursively calling eachother. The following code does the trick:

```
var userScroll1 = true;
var userScroll2 = true;
var timer;

$div1.scroll(function() {
  if(userScroll2) {
    userScroll1 = false;
    clearTimeout(timer);
    $div2.scrollTop($div1.scrollTop());
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
       userScroll1 = true;
     }, 100);
  }
});
$div2.scroll(function(){
  if(userScroll1) {
    userScroll2 = false;
    clearTimeout(timer);
    $div1.scrollTop($div2.scrollTop());
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
       userScroll2 = true;
     }, 100);
  }
});
```

Check out the properly functioning jsbin: https://jsfiddle.net/axtn/a91fsar3